# JAXB: A cycle is detected in the object graph

Tags: java, jaxb

I have twi entities. Category entity:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "EPBS_DATA.NEWS_CATEGORY")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "id", "name", "news" })
public class CategoryEntity {
    public final static String ID_GENERATOR_NAME =
    "EPBS_DATA.sq_news_category";
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                generator = ID_GENERATOR_NAME)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = ID_GENERATOR_NAME,
                   sequenceName = ID_GENERATOR_NAME, allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_NAME", nullable = false, length = 1024)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "news")
    @XmlElement(name = "")
    private List<NewsEntity> news = new ArrayList<NewsEntity>();

    setters/getters
}
```

and NewsEntity

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "EPBS_DATA.NEWS")
@XmlType(propOrder =
     { "id", "body", "lead", "creatorId", "date", "federal", "regId",
       "raw", "file", "title", "editDate", "fixed", "categories",
       "publishDates" })
public class NewsEntity {
    public final static String ID_GENERATOR_NAME = "EPBS_DATA.SQ_EPBS";
    public final static String GET_NEWS_BY_DATE = "NewsEntity.getNewsByDate";
    public final static String GET_NEWS_COUNT = "NewsEntity.getNewsCount";
    public final static String GET_DATES = "NewsEntity.getDates";
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NEWS_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                generator = ID_GENERATOR_NAME)
@SequenceGenerator(name = ID_GENERATOR_NAME,
                   sequenceName = ID_GENERATOR_NAME, allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "NEWS_BODY", nullable = true)
    @Lob
    private String body;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "EPBS_DATA.NEWS_CATEGORY_ASSIGMENT",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_NEWS",
                                     referencedColumnName = "NEWS_ID"),
           inverseJoinColumns =
           @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CATEGORY", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "news")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "categories")
    @XmlElement(name = "")
    private List<CategoryEntity> categories = new ArrayList<CategoryEntity>();
```

I have error A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: jpa.news.CategoryEntity@79c7b9d3 -> jpa.news.NewsEntity@31453ead -> jpa.news.CategoryEntity@79c7b9d3]

I try use @XmlTransient and @XmlInverseReference, but whatever i have error.

Comment: Isnt this data - jpa.news.NewsEntity@31453ead references itself? What is your data for this?

Comment: A cycle in your object graph is nothing to do with the JPA API, since any JPA provider can cope with such things. That is XML only. So remove the JPA tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your beans refer to each other: CategoryEntity.news contains at least one NewsEntity whose property categories contains the aforementioned CategroyEntity. Trying to output this as an XML would lead to an endless circle. Depending on what your "leading" Entity is you have to mark either categories or news as @XmlTransient.